# Printing from mobile device from browser

Tags: ios, mobile, printing

We are in the process of creating a web app that has print capabilities, and would like to be able to support this functionality on as many devices as possible. Our users are specifically using iPads, but we will eventually want to support other devices. I've seen that iOS now uses AirPrint, but what about printers that don't support this? Is there any way to cover that from a web app standpoint or are other measures necessary?

Comment: We will also want to support android going forward. Currently, iOS is more important, but this is equally a question for how to print on Android devices as well.

Comment: then tag `android` when it is important

Comment: I'm saying I would like to know about both now so I can code with that requirement in mind, but iOS is the more pressing business concern.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this App: https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/printer-pro/id393313223?mt=8
If it's an option you could use it, or come up with something on your own, but it is possible.

Comment: I've seen some apps like this, but I was wondering if there's anything that can be done from the web app side of things rather than just depending on AirPrint or an external app, but it looks like this may be the only solution.